# How to add blocks to an already existing notion page

Tags: notion-api

I'm currently working on a little project where a script adds recipes into a notion database.
My current problem is that I can't find a way (I found nothing i the API Docs) to add blocks (like checkboxes or headings) to the content of a page after it was created.

So my question is if there is a way to add blocks to an existing notion page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would advise to take a look at [Append block children](https://developers.notion.com/reference/patch-block-children). If I get the question correct, this might be what you need.

(Note that the so called `block_id` can be a `page_id` as well.)

Comment: I didn't knew that you could use the page_id as block_id. They should explain it more in the docs. Thanks!

Comment: Agreed. There is one single sentence at the top of https://developers.notion.com/reference/block
That's all.