# Adding a block to a Notion page in Python using the API - How to resolve a '400 invalid_request_url' error?

Tags: python, api, notion-api, notion

I can't add a block to a page using a Notion API. I've already tried the queries and functions detailed in the documentation, but I still got a 400 error:

`Error: 400 {"object":"error","status":400,"code":"invalid_request_url","message":"Invalid request URL."}`

I'm using Python 3.8.2

I created this class:

```
class NotionConnection:

    def __init__(self, sec_token, database_id: str):
        self.database_id = database_id
        self.headers = {
            "Authorization": "Bearer " + sec_token,
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Notion-Version": "2022-06-28",
        }

    def get_page(self):
        url = f'https://api.notion.com/v1/databases/{self.database_id}/query'
        payload = {'page_size': 100}
        r = requests.post(url, json=payload, headers = self.headers)

        result_dict = r.json()

        with open('db.json', 'w', encoding='utf8') as f:
            json.dump(result_dict, f, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)
        
        results = result_dict['results']

        return results

    def add_block_children(self, page_id, data:dict):
        #page_id_edited = page_id.replace('-','')
        #print(page_id_edited) #I already tried removing the scores
        url = f"https://api.notion.com/v1/blocks/{page_id}/children"
        block_data = {
            "object": "block",
            "type": "paragraph",
            "paragraph": {
                "text": [
                    {
                        "type": "text",
                        "text": {
                            "content": data
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }

        r = requests.post(url, headers=self.headers, json=block_data)

        if r.status_code == 200:
            print("Block added")
        else:
            print("Error:", r.status_code, r.text)
```

Then, my procedure to add a block is the following:

```
import os
from notion_connection import NotionConnection
import json
from datetime import datetime, timezone

NOTION_TOKEN = os.getenv('NOTION_TOKEN')
DATABASE_ID = os.getenv('DATABASE_ID')


notion_database = NotionConnection(NOTION_TOKEN, DATABASE_ID)

page_dict = notion_database.get_page()
print(page_dict[0])

notion_database.add_block_children(page_dict[0]['id'], 'Test')
```

Although the [documentation](https://developers.notion.com/reference/patch-block-children) indicates the use of `block_id` instead of `page_id`, [I have read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73569806/how-to-add-blocks-to-an-already-existing-notion-page) that it can be overridden by adding a first block to the page, which is the case for me.